# Проблема с устанновкой WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Сделал все по инструкции по установки `WopdPress`, а он мне вот такое выкинул:

> `To change this page, upload your website into the public_html directory`
> (Чтобы изменить эту страницу, загрузите ваш сайт в директорию `public_html`).

Что мне с этим делать?

Answer (score 1):

Это ВордПресс выдаёт по умолчанию, сразу после установки, и это правильно! Чтобы он выдавал чего-то нужное, надо туда сперва ваш контент засунуть (желательно через http://имя_сайта/wp-login.php?). Об этом там и сказано.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри есть ли в корневой папке файлик index.html если есть удали его